# How do I configure Babun to work with Meteor?

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin, cmd.exe, conemu

I've tried adding the Meteor plugin in the .zshrc file like so:

```
plugins=(git meteor)
```

I couldn't find any documentation on http://babun.github.io/faq.html that would answer this question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add meteor path to your .zshrc file.

For example Meteor's path on my computer is :
**C:\Users\raitom\AppData\Local.meteor**

Inside Babun open your **~/.zshrc** file and search that line :

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Below write a new line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/C/Users/raitom/AppData/Local/.meteor`

( Replace this path with yours)

Then relaunch a bubun terminal (or type **source ~/.zshrc**) and you should be able to use meteor everywhere by typing:

**meteor.bat < command >**

Comment: From user [VULCHOK](http://superuser.com/users/539539/vulchok):  I suggest that you add an alias to avoid the ".bat":  export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH  ;  export PATH=$PATH:C:/Users/YOURUSER/AppData/Local/.meteor  ;  alias meteor='meteor.bat'